# Mysterious padding in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap navbar, I want to do border-left on every li class, but it's ugly because of mysterious padding in navbar class,

As you can see, this border doesn't reach the bottom of `<li>` element. How can I remove this empty space?

I already removed all paddings from navbar, but nothing happens.

Comment: First, add your code here

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: but what can i do with it? When i modify line-height and font size it doesnt make a difference, its still visible

Comment: try adding `!important;` at the end of your CSS styles your trying to add. That way it should force to use `!important` ones I.E. `font-size: 14px !important;`.

Comment: @Toxide82 That won't help at all. `!important` is never a solution, except in extreme circumstances.

Comment: it was a simple suggestion to see if they styles he was trying to set would work... that's all.

Comment: @MrLister You're right, that doesnt make a difference.

Comment: You should add the code you're trying to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `border-top` property on active `a` elements:

```
border-top: 4px solid #df5330;
```

Try adding this property to default `a` elements :

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}
```